# How can I write parameterized ADO.NET SQL queries that are portable between ODBC and SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, odbc, prepared-statement

I have a codebase that uses ADO.NET SQL queries using `@parameterName` to refer to parameters. I need to make this code portable so that it can be run against an `OdbcConnection` rather than just a `SqlConnection`. One issue I've come across is that ODBC uses `?` to refer to parameters instead of `@parameterName`.

There are obviously various ways I can work around this (e.g. forking the code based on the connection type), but I'm wondering if there are any established patterns for handling this particular incompatibility.

Note: I know that in general making SQL portable across database technologies is a fraught exercise (especially without an ORM); I'm specifically just curious whether there is a workaround for this particular issue.

Comment: you write a wrapper, so that all go over the wrapper, you do the same as an orm